# How to display data from created custom registration fields on user account (Drupal 8)

Tags: drupal, entity

I have created a custom display view for the registration page and added some custom fields when user registers as shown in the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

When I check the profiles for new registered user. I do not see the custom field I have created which is `first name` as shown in the screenshot below. How do I render the custom field in the event some changes need to be made

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't checked the checked box in the field settings.Go to custom field settings which u have created there u will find a check box name 'display on user registration form'.

Comment: Yah, I've read about that but I can't seem to find it. I'm using `Drupal 8` by the way